# How to write a Scala regular expression to capture all the quoted contents between two double quotes(including the escaped quote marks)?

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

How to write a Scala regular expression to capture all the quoted contents between two double quotes(including the escaped quote marks)?

My aim is to find the first (unescaped) quotation mark(which is part of the string), find the paired (unescaped) quotation mark(which is also part of the string), then extract everything between them.

I'm expecting something like this:

```
"""??""".r findFirstMatchIn(""""abcdef\"abc"""") // Note that the real string begins from the fourth quotation marks, i.e. the real string is "abcdef\"abc"
res = Some(abcdef\"abc)

"""??""".r findFirstMatchIn(""""abcdef\"abc\t\t"""")
res = Some(abcdef\"abc\t\t)

"""??""".r findFirstMatchIn(""""abcdef\"abc\t\"\t"""")
res = Some(abcdef\"abc\t\"\t)
```

I tried something like `"""([^\"])*([\\\\]+[\"tnbr/])+([^\"]*)*""".r` but it does not work for string `"abcdef\"abc\t\"\t"`

Any hints are appreciated.

edit:

My intention is to extract every character between paired double quotes:

"abc" => abc

"abc\n" => abc\n

"\t\n" => \t\n

"\\" => \\

"\" => This is wrong(so it will never happen) because the second quotation mark is escaped hence the double quotes are not paired

"abc\" => abc\"

"hello\\"world\"" => This is also wrong(so it will never happen) because \ is escaped and the quotation mark are not properly escaped

"hello\\\"world\\\"" => hello\\\"world\\\"

The escaped char can be:
\" \\ \n \t \b \r \f \/
otherwise it is just plain texts.

edit:

my string is JSON style like:

"abc": "value"
or "abc\t\n\"def": "value"

and my aim is to extract abc or abc\t\n\"def before the colon.

so to summarize:

my aim is to find the first (unescaped) quotation mark(which is part of the string), find the paired (unescaped) quotation mark(which is also part of the string), then extract everything between them.

Comment: What should happen with `"""hello\\"world\\""""`? (the backslashes are escaped, not the double quotes); The expected output in your question is unclear: it's always the same as the input string. How is one supposed to understand what the matched group is?

Comment: You need to refine your question. As it is, the regex pattern `".*"` provides the correct solution to all your test cases.

Comment: @jwvh The problem is that the `toString` of  `Match` doesn't show anything meaningful. The output simply doesn't say anything, because you can't distinguish the groups in the match...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
"((?:[^"\\]|\\[\\"ntbrf])+)"
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JWXhCS/1)

In Scala code:

```
val regex = """"((?:[^"\\]|\\[\\"ntbrf])+)"""".r
val examples = List(
  """"abc"""",
  """"abc\n"""",
  """"\t\n"""",
  """"\\"""",
  """"abc\""""",
  """"hello\\\"world\""""",
  """"hello\\\"world\\\""""",
  """"abc": """,
  """"value" """,
  """or "abc\t\n\"def"""",
  """: "value"""",
  """abc"def\"abc"""",
  """abc"def\"abc\t\t"""",
  """abc"def\"abc\t\"\t""""
)

for (e <- examples) {
  println(regex.findFirstMatchIn(e).get.group(1))
}
```

Output:

```
abc
abc\n
\t\n
\\
abc\"
hello\\\"world\"
hello\\\"world\\\"
abc
value
abc\t\n\"def
value
def\"abc
def\"abc\t\t
def\"abc\t\"\t
```

Comment: @CodingNow Cannot confirm. If the string is `dq, bs, dq, dq`, (**d**ouble **q**uote, **b**ack **s**lash), then a backslash followed by double quote is returned. Maybe something went wrong in your comment: the backticks in comments work somehow weirdly sometimes.

Comment: Yes. Just confirmed that it is the backtick issue which is rather annoying(it is quite challenging to figure out the correct number of the backticks) and I managed to circumvent it. Thank you so much for your kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

I just use

"""([^"\]|\"|\t|\n|\b|\r|\/|\f)*""".r

and it seems like working.

Thank you.

Comment: This does not enforce that the string literal is enclosed in double quotes, and I don't see what is is supposed to do with `\\\`